# Angular 5 google maps : show only markers in radius of # kilometers

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm currently making a map in my app. I'm using the amazing Angular agm package for this.

The goal is to display a map with markers. These markers come from the database and contain latitude and longitude values. I have hundreds of markers and I want to filter those. I only want to display the markers that are within a distance e.g 5 kilometers of my location. How do I this? I went through the API docs of the package, but I don't see the solution. Anyone can help me?

**Map.component.html**

```
<!-- this creates a google map on the page with the given lat/lng from -->
<!-- the component as the initial center of the map: -->
<agm-map
        [latitude]="lat"
        [longitude]="lng"
        [fullscreenControl]="true"
        [zoom]="13"
>

    <agm-marker
            *ngFor="let marker of markers"
            [latitude]="marker.latitude"
            [longitude]="marker.longitude"
            (markerClick)="doSomething($event)"

            >
        <agm-info-window [disableAutoPan]="true">
            <a routerLink="/">Go there</a>
        </agm-info-window>
    </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

**map.component.ts**

```
export class FindLocalsComponent implements OnInit{

    lat:number;
    lng: number;
    markers = [];

    constructor(private findLocalsService: FindLocalsService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        let token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        this.findLocalsService.getLocations(token)
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data.obj);
                this.lat = data.obj.myLocation[0].latitude;
                this.lng = data.obj.myLocation[0].longitude;
                this.markers = data.obj.locationCollection;
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for a `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween` function which returns the distance between two points (in meters)

The list of changes:

a) import `geometry` library:

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: '--key goes here--',
  libraries: ['geometry']
})
```

b) to utilize `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween` function, Google Maps API needs to be loaded first. For that matter  [`MapsAPILoader` provider](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/injectables/MapsAPILoader.html)  is utilized as demonstrated below

c) perform markers filtering by distance

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.markers = this.getLocations(); //original list of markers data

    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      const center = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);
      //markers located within 50 km distance from center are included
      this.filteredMarkers = this.markers.filter(m => {
        const markerLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(m.latitude, m.longitude);
        const  distanceInKm = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerLoc, center) / 1000;
        if (distanceInKm < 50.0) {
          return m;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zke9)

Answer (score 2):

In **Angular**, by using **@agm** library, we can easily do that.

[image]

Create a draggable and resizable circle used as a radius:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom">


    <ng-container *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index">

        <agm-marker (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label, i)" [latitude]="m.lat" [longitude]="m.lng" [label]="m.label" [iconUrl]="m.icon" *ngIf="m.isShown">

            <agm-info-window>
                <div>{{m.content}}</div>
            </agm-info-window>

        </agm-marker>

    </ng-container>

    <agm-circle [latitude]="radiusLat" [longitude]="radiusLong" [radius]="radius" [fillColor]="'red'"
        [circleDraggable]="true" [editable]="false" (dragEnd)="radiusDragEnd($event)"
        (radiusChange)="event('radiusChange',$event)">
    </agm-circle>

</agm-map>

<div>Latitude: {{latitude}}</div>
<div>Longitude: {{longitude}}</div>
```

We need to check the Radius and its distance between each marker to show/ hide it while dragging.

```
  radiusDragEnd($event: any) {
    console.log($event);
    this.radiusLat = $event.coords.lat;
    this.radiusLong = $event.coords.lng;
    this.showHideMarkers();
  }

  event(type,$event) {
    console.log(type,$event);
    this.radius = $event;
    this.showHideMarkers();
  }

  showHideMarkers(){
    Object.values(this.markers).forEach(value => {
      value.isShown = this.getDistanceBetween(value.lat,value.lng,this.radiusLat,this.radiusLong);
    });
  }

  getDistanceBetween(lat1,long1,lat2,long2){
    var from = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1,long1);
    var to = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2,long2);

    if(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(from,to) <= this.radius){    
      console.log('Radius',this.radius);
      console.log('Distance Between',google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
        from,to
      ));
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Check this link for the tutorial:
**Source [link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/show-markers-in-draggable-radius-on-angular-google-maps/)**

You can find demo here:
**Demo [link](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/Angular/angular-google-maps-with-radius-circle-markers/)**